# Checkbox form validator Angularjs2

Tags: angular

I need to validate something like this. In the following form, SignUp button should be enabled only if user checked the checkbox. If user uncheck the checkbox the button should get disabled.

Following way enabled the button when user check the checkbox for the first time. But then if user uncheck the checkbox again the button remain enabled which actually should be disabled. All help appreciated. Thanks!

```
<form id="login-form" action="" method="post" role="form"  #loginForm='ngForm'>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" required maxlength="12" minlength="12" required [(ngModel)]="user.ssn" name="ssn" #name="ngModel" tabindex="1" class="form-control input-box" placeholder=""
                            value="" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>

        <div class="form-group center">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="chkTerm" ngModel name="cb" #cb="ngModel" required  />
          <label for="chkTerm"></label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="center">

                                <button class="btn" (click)='clicked()' class="btn waves-effect waves-light" [disabled]="!loginForm.form.valid" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': '#57e5a1'}" type="submit" name="action">SignUp</button>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: Which version of angular2 are you using?

Comment: @Isuru, have you tired my solution, let me how does it go I can fix it.